# VSCode Vim Settings not working for remaps with "

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I have this in my `settings.json` for preventing vim from replacing my clipboard when I delete something:

```
  "vim.visualModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
      "before": ["<leader>", "d"],
      "after": ["\"_d"]
    },
    {
      "before": ["<leader>", "p"],
      "after": ["\"_dP"]
    }
  ],
```

I have other settings which work just not this one. I suspect its the `\"` in the `after` setting, not sure if that's really the problem. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

```json
{
  "vim.visualModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
      "before": ["<leader>", "d"],
      "after": ["\"", "_", "d"]
    },
    {
      "before": ["<leader>", "p"],
      "after": ["\"", "_", "d", "P"]
    }
  ]
}
```